# WPF WebBrowser font size change functionality

Tags: c#, wpf, browser, webbrowser-control

I want to be able to scale the font size of my WebBrowser control with a button.

Currently, I can do something like

```
    IHTMLDocument2 doc = myBrowser.Document as IHTMLDocument2;

        if (doc != null)
        {
            doc.execCommand("SelectAll", false, null);
            doc.execCommand("FontSize", false, someSize);
            doc.execCommand("Unselect", false, null);
        }
    }
```

Which basically selects all the content in my WebBrowser, changes the font size, and deselects.  The problem with this is that it sets the WHOLE document to the same font size, and it's not relative, which means if I have a header or something with some paragraphs, then the header and paragraph will have the same size after I press the button.

Sniffing around at the IHTMLDocument2 interface API, there isn't a command that allows me to select a subset of the document, which means I'm basically not able to do what I want to do.  I'm wondering if there is anywhere else I can access the font size attribute of the child elements inside that IHTMLDocument2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
IHTMLDocument2 doc = webBrowser.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
doc.parentWindow.execScript("document.body.style.zoom=" + browserFontSize.ToString().Replace(",", ".") + ";");
```

Where `webBrowser` is your WebBrowser and `browserFontSize` is the double value (larger than 0, not sure what the cap is) you want to scale your WebBrowser to.

This will only work if your IE is v7.0+